# Order rows in join table mysql

Tags: mysql, join

I have a table with date ranges. I want to look for gaps between these ranges.
I've figured out that I may left join table to itself and calculate the difference.

Current table:

```
date_begin    date_end
2010-08-01    2010-08-15
2010-08-16    2010-08-30
2010-08-31    2010-09-12
2010-10-01    2010-10-15
```

I want to get:

```
date_begin    date_end    -   date_begin2    DATEDIFF(date_begin2 - date_end)
                              2010-08-01       
2010-08-01    2010-08-15      2010-08-16       ...
2010-08-16    2010-08-30      2010-08-31       ...
2010-08-31    2010-09-12      2010-10-01       ...
2010-10-01    2010-10-15
```

I use the following query:

```
SELECT pay1.date_begin, pay1.date_end, 
       pay2.date_begin, pay2.date_end, DATEDIFF( pay2.date_begin, pay1.date_end) 
FROM `payment_employees` AS pay1
LEFT JOIN `payment_employees` AS pay2 ON pay2.date_begin > pay1.date_end
GROUP BY pay1.date_begin
ORDER BY pay1.date_begin ASC
```

But the result is

```
pay1.date_begin date_end    pay2.date_begin date_end              difference
2010-08-01    2010-08-15    2010-08-31    2010-09-12            16  wrong
2010-08-16    2010-08-30    2010-08-31    2010-09-12            1   correct
2010-08-31    2010-09-12    2010-10-01    2010-10-15            19  correct
2010-10-01    2010-10-15    NULL              NULL
```

If I delete the GROUP BY I can see that there are correct rows in the result. I just can't figure out how to get them.

Is there a way to sort table before being joined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the rows in your tables sorted before being joined, you could replace either or both of the real tables in your join with derived tables like this...

```
SELECT pay1.date_begin,
       pay1.date_end, 
       pay2.date_begin,
       pay2.date_end,
       DATEDIFF( pay2.date_begin, pay1.date_end) 
    FROM (SELECT *
              FROM `payment_employees`
              ORDER BY date_begin) AS pay1
          LEFT JOIN (SELECT *
                         FROM `payment_employees`
                         ORDER BY date_end) AS pay2
             ON pay2.date_begin > pay1.date_end
    GROUP BY pay1.date_begin
    ORDER BY pay1.date_begin ASC
```

I'm not sure if that'll solve the substantive problem, though.

Comment: Yeah. I think I'll do something with subquery. Thanks